# What is the best way to say this sentence? à l'Internet vs à internet

Tags: grammaire, usage, articles

I would like to translate this as literal as possible in French. I have a few recommendations that vary slightly. I'm also not sure if I should use "à l'Internet" or "à internet". Any help would be greatly appreciated. If none of these sentences work, or could use some tweaking, please advise. Thank you.

Original sentence:

> I am often away from my telephone and cannot always access the internet.

Possibilities:

1. > Je suis souvent loin de mon téléphone et n'ai pas toujours accès à internet.
2. > Je suis souvent loin de mon téléphone et ne peux pas toujours avoir accès à l'Internet.
3. > Je suis régulièrement sans accès à mon téléphone et à internet.

Answer (score 1):

The good translation for :
"I am often away from my telephone and cannot always access the internet."
Is :
"Je suis souvent loin de mon téléphone et ne peux pas toujours accéder à internet ."

There is no article for internet in usage even so internet is a common noun. 
I read that some french deputy are asking we change this usage and put the article "l'".

Comment: As a french speaker, I would say `...ne peux pas toujours avoir accès à internet` instead of `..accéder à internet`. I cannot explain why but it seems better for me

Comment: As a french, I would say both translations "accéder à internet" or "avoir accès à internet" are correct. I used the verb "accéder" to be as literal as possible as asked by bonjour.